# Joining 2 XML's with document function is very slow

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, talend

I have XML i need to join on the ID

XML input ( 93 Mb )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Partner>
      <ID>186561</ID>
   </Partner>
   ...
<root>
```

XML : fuzzymatched.xml ( 40 Mb )

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
   <Partner>
    <ID>186561</ID>
    <FUZZYMATCH>71</FUZZYMATCH>
  </Partner>
  ...
<root>
```

When i join this files with following XSLT , it is very slow. It seems that it opens the big document every time again?! Is there a better solution? or am i doing something wrong.
I use the XSLT engine of Talend Open Studio

XSLT file

```
<!-- ********************************************* -->
<!-- fuzzymatch_joiner.xsl : -->
<!-- ********************************************* -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:variable name="vPartners" select="document('file:///c:/temp/fuzzymatched.xml')/root" />

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Partner"></xsl:apply-templates>          
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!-- ********************************************* -->

<xsl:template match="Partner">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$vPartners/Partner[ID = current()/ID]/FUZZYMATCH"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!-- ********************************************* -->

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!-- ********************************************* -->

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4):

Due to the size of your XML file, you need to change the parser set by default (DOM) and use SAX parser instead.

On tFileInputXML component, select the **advanced parameters** and choose **SAX parser** (labelled : "*low memory consuming*" if I remember well).
The xml processing should be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should definitely use a key (`<xsl:key>` and `key()`) to index the IDs from fuzzymatched.xml, to speed up ID lookup. That should make a huge difference.

If that's not enough... I don't know much about Talend, but I would try the same transformation using a good optimized XSLT processor such as Saxon, and see how the performance compares. An XSLT processor shouldn't have to re-open the file referenced by `document()` every time.

Do you have the freedom to use a different processor within Talend?

XSLT 3.0 (still in working draft status) provides support for streaming, which would reduce the memory requirements for the input XML, and could speed things up. Saxon has support for it.

But I think just using `key()` should speed things up for you a lot.